# RabbitMQ - How to save message for new consumer

Tags: rabbitmq, chat

Working on a new chat project, We want to use RabbitMQ to transfer our message.

So can RabbitMQ save all the message in queue or some other place,  when an new people(consumer) comes, the RabbitMQ can flush the saved message to the new people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a persistent queue, rabbitmq can store the messages (the messages are stored in the same mnesia-db path).
So suppose that each user has a own queue, when the user gets on line can download the messages.

Anyway I don’t think it is a good idea use rmq to push messages for chat. There are others appropriate technologies, like MQTT, XMPP.

I suggest to read this post:
[using rabbitmq in android for chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158842/using-rabbitmq-in-android-for-chat)

Comment: RabbitMQ **does not store messages on Mnesia**.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [the tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html) to understand what RabbitMQ is.

> RabbitMQ is a message broker: it accepts and forwards messages. You can think about it as a post office: when you put the mail that you want posting in a post box, you can be sure that Mr. or Ms. Mailperson will eventually deliver the mail to your recipient. In this analogy, RabbitMQ is a post box, a post office and a postman.

Comment: So use rabbitmq is not a good idea for a chat program? because it transfer mail to my recipient and don't have an copy left.

Comment: Here You can see this use case: http://videlalvaro.github.io/2011/05/rabbitmq-chat-post-mortem.html